# Admin Dashboard Background Image not full when in smaller width

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, tailwind-css, flowbite

im trying to make admin dashboard page, i use vue3 and tailwind,flowbite, and vue-flowbite. I Manage to make it like this[image: picture]

but i notice something there's scrollball in the bottom of the page, when i check it, something was wrong it become like this
[image: picture]

i dont know what's wrong, there's some gap and when the screen is smaller the gap become even bigger. here the code:

component SideBar.vue

```
<template>
  <div
    class="w-72 flex flex-col sticky top-0 min-h-screen items-center bg-white"
  >
    <div class="w-full sticky top-0">
      <img
        alt="bibaliLogoWhite"
        :src="require(`@/assets/bibaliBg.png`)"
        class="w-24 mt-7 mx-auto"
      />
      <div
        class="mt-10 flex flex-col items-end space-y-3 text-[#333333] w-full"
      >
        <router-link
          to="/dashboard/admin"
          class="flex w-[200px] a h-full rounded-l-full flex-row justify-end py-2"
        >
          <p>Manage Admin</p>
          <i class="fas fa-user-shield mt-1 mr-6 ml-3"></i>
        </router-link>

        <router-link
          to="/dashboard/karyawan"
          class="flex w-[200px] a h-full rounded-l-full flex-row justify-end py-2"
        >
          <p>Manage Karyawan</p>
          <i class="fas fa-user-group mt-1 mr-6 ml-3"></i>
        </router-link>
        <router-link
          to="/dashboard/nilai-karyawan"
          class="flex w-[200px] a h-full rounded-l-full flex-row justify-end py-2"
        >
          <p>Nilai Karyawan</p>
          <i class="fas fa-chart-line mt-1 mr-6 ml-3"></i>
        </router-link>
        <router-link
          to="/dashboard/spk"
          class="flex w-[200px] a h-full rounded-l-full flex-row justify-end py-2"
        >
          <p>SPK</p>
          <i class="fas fa-calculator mt-1 mr-6 ml-3"></i>
        </router-link>
        <router-link
          to="/dashboard/ewa"
          class="flex w-[200px] a h-full rounded-l-full flex-row justify-end py-2"
        >
          <p>EWA</p>
          <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-dollar mt-1 mr-6 ml-3"></i>
        </router-link>
        <router-link
          to="/dashboard/news"
          class="flex w-[200px] a h-full rounded-l-full flex-row justify-end py-2"
        >
          <p>News</p>
          <i class="fa-regular fa-newspaper mt-1 mr-6 ml-3"></i>
        </router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SideBar",
};
</script>

<style scoped>
a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #bb0c06 0%, #fb2f01 35%, #ff8f63 100%);

  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
a.router-link-active {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #bb0c06 0%, #fb2f01 35%, #ff8f63 100%);

  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.bg-custom {
  background: rgb(251, 47, 1);
  background: linear-gradient(
    266deg,
    rgba(251, 47, 1, 1) 60%,
    rgba(255, 143, 99, 1) 100%
  );
}
</style>
```

and this is component NavBar.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="h-16 bg-red-primary z-50 drop-shadow-lg">
    <dropdown placement="bottom" class="float-right rounded-3xl z-50 mt-1">
      <template #trigger>
        <div
          class="flex mr-5 cursor-pointer mb-3 hover:bg-red-primary-600 rounded-2xl justify-center text-white"
        >
          <div class="flex flex-col mt-2 px-2 pb-1">
            <div>Roland Brilianto</div>
            <div>Jabatan</div>
          </div>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down fa-lg my-auto ml-5 px-2 pb-1"></i>
        </div>
      </template>
      <div class="p-2 tex-right z-50">
        <div class="hover:bg-slate-100 w-24 py-2 pl-2 cursor-pointer">
          <i class="fa-regular fa-user fa-lg mr-2"></i>
          Profile
        </div>
        <div class="hover:bg-slate-100 w-24 py-2 pl-2 cursor-pointer">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket fa-lg"></i>
          Logout
        </div>
      </div>
    </dropdown>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Dropdown } from "flowbite-vue";
export default {
  components: {
    Dropdown,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.tes {
  color: #f3f3f3;
}
</style>
```

and there is a folder called Dashboard where i put all the components together, here is the index.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="flex">
    <side-bar />
    <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
      <nav-bar class="sticky top-0" />
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import SideBar from "@/components/SideBar.vue";
import NavBar from "@/components/NavBar.vue";
export default {
  name: "DashboardIndex",
  components: {
    SideBar,
    NavBar,
  },
};
</script>
```

and in that folder too contain another file called ManageAdmin.vue and here is the code:

```
<template>
  <div class="text-center">testest</div>
  <div class="mx-20 bg-white rounded-xl">
    <div class="flex flex-row justify-between py-3">
      <div class="flex flex-row pl-3">
        <label
          for="countries"
          class="block mb-2 mr-2 my-auto text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
          >Show</label
        >
        <select
          id="countries"
          class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-20 p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
        >
          <option selected value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
        </select>
        <label
          for="countries"
          class="block mb-2 mr-2 ml-2 my-auto text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
          >Entries</label
        >
      </div>
      <div>
        <button-primary class="mr-7 py-2 px-2">Add Karyawan</button-primary>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div
      class="relative overflow-x-auto max-w-[950px] mx-auto overflow-y-auto max-h-[400px] shadow-md sm:rounded-lg"
    >
      <table class="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
        <thead
          class="text-xs text-white sticky top-0 uppercase bg-red-primary dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400"
        >
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="p-4">
              <div class="flex items-center">
                <input
                  id="checkbox-all-search"
                  type="checkbox"
                  class="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 dark:focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600"
                />
                <label for="checkbox-all-search" class="sr-only"
                  >checkbox</label
                >
              </div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">Product name</th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">Color</th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">Category</th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">Accesories</th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">Available</th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">Price</th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">Weight</th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr
            class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-600"
          >
            <td class="w-4 p-4">
              <div class="flex items-center">
                <input
                  id="checkbox-table-search-1"
                  type="checkbox"
                  class="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 dark:focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600"
                />
                <label for="checkbox-table-search-1" class="sr-only"
                  >checkbox</label
                >
              </div>
            </td>
            <th
              scope="row"
              class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white"
            >
              Apple MacBook Pro 17"
            </th>
            <td class="px-6 py-4">Silver</td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4">Laptop</td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4">Yes</td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4">Yes</td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4">$2999</td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4">3.0 lb.</td>
            <td class="flex items-center px-6 py-4 space-x-3">
              <a
                href="#"
                class="font-medium text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500 hover:underline"
                >Edit</a
              >
              <a
                href="#"
                class="font-medium text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 hover:underline"
                >Remove</a
              >
            </td>
          </tr>
          
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-col items-center pb-2">
      <!-- Help text -->
      <span class="text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
        Showing
        <span class="font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">1</span> to
        <span class="font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">10</span> of
        <span class="font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">100</span>
        Entries
      </span>
      <div class="inline-flex mt-2 xs:mt-0">
        <!-- Buttons -->
        <button
          class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-red-primary rounded-l hover:bg-red-primary-600 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white"
        >
          <svg
            aria-hidden="true"
            class="w-5 h-5 mr-2"
            fill="currentColor"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M7.707 14.707a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414l4-4a1 1 0 011.414 1.414L5.414 9H17a1 1 0 110 2H5.414l2.293 2.293a1 1 0 010 1.414z"
              clip-rule="evenodd"
            ></path>
          </svg>
          Prev
        </button>
        <button
          class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-red-primary border-0 border-l border-gray-700 rounded-r hover:bg-red-primary-600 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white"
        >
          Next
          <svg
            aria-hidden="true"
            class="w-5 h-5 ml-2"
            fill="currentColor"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M12.293 5.293a1 1 0 011.414 0l4 4a1 1 0 010 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L14.586 11H3a1 1 0 110-2h11.586l-2.293-2.293a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
              clip-rule="evenodd"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</template>

<script>
import ButtonPrimary from "@/components/ButtonPrimary.vue";
export default {
  mounted() {},
  components: {
    ButtonPrimary,
  },
  
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

and of course on top of everything there's app.vue here's the code:

```
<template>
  <div
    id="app"
    class="bg-red-secondary min-h-screen"
    :style="{
      'background-image': 'url(' + require(`@/assets/bibaliBg-black.png`) + ')',
    }"
  >
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

these thing is really hard for me i've been trying to fixed it for like 5 hours and i can't. Please help me i will be really grateful for your help. sorry for the long code because i dont know where it went wrong. thanks